# How can I set up nginx reverse proxy for any subdomains?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I installed **nginx** at my Ubuntu VPS for listening any petition at port 80 and doing reverse proxy to different server technologies.

This is my configuration file like:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name subdomain.example.com;
        location / {

                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2311;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        }

}
```

However, I think there must be a way for writing a wildcard for ***any*** subdomain.

I tried with

```
server_name *.example.com;
```

But got not results.

Also I wonder, what will it happen for appended routes like:

```
example.com/route
```

or

```
example.com/folder
```

And, what about AJAX calls to self routes?

Comment: What "but got no results" mean?

Comment: If I tried subdomain1.example.com at browser I will take me to the nginx default site, not to right the subdomain

Comment: Have you restarted your nginx? `*.example.com` works perfectly for me and tons of our company sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is

```
server_name ~ .*.example.com
```

The tilde is what makes it a regex